# Is there a good way to set headerRight to pass onPress event in React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

my friends, hope you doing well, I need some help with my React Native project.
I have the following code and struggling with the navigation for the "NewPost" screen.
I want to create a button in the header and handle press on it but can not figure out how to do it. Thanks for your precious help:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Provider } from './src/context/BlogContext';
import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen';
import CreatePost from './src/screens/CreatePost';
import ShowScreen from './src/screens/ShowScreen';

import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const App = ({navigation}) => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Index'>
        <Stack.Screen name='Index' 
          component={IndexScreen} 
          options={{ 
            title: 'Blogs', 
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>
                <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )   
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' component={ShowScreen} options={{ title: 'Post Details' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='NewPost' component={CreatePost} options={{ title: 'Create a Post' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand what's the actual issue you are getting ? Can you explain more.

Comment: Hello there! Usually, I create a stack Navigator like this:
**<Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' component={ShowScreen} options={{ title: 'Post Details' }} />**
And then refer to it using the name props like that:
const ResultsList = ({navigation }) => {  
     return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           **<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ShowResults')}>**
                       <ResultsDetails result={item} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
                    ) 
                }}                
            />
        </View>
    )
}

Comment: But now I create a stack screen and then I use the headerRight props to add a button in the header : 
<Stack.Screen name='Index' 
          component={IndexScreen} 
          options={{ 
            title: 'Blogs', 
            **headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>
                <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )**   
        }} />

Comment: So now I want to know how to make this onPress event work to show another screen:
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. I have added my answer please check.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you cannot access `navigation` outside of the `NavigationContainer` so remove `navigation` from your `App` declaration :

```js
const App = ({}) => { // remove navigation object from here
```

Now, to do user redirection on headerRight press, you can actually access `naviagation` on your `headerRight` and navigation user as below :

```js
 headerRight: ({navigation}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>
    <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Kishan, this is a very good approach, even when it returns an error it gives me the idea to destructure the **({navigation})** inside the **"options"** instead. Thank you so much. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use useNavigation hook to implement the navigation In the navigator component.

For Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Provider } from './src/context/BlogContext';
import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen';
import CreatePost from './src/screens/CreatePost';
import ShowScreen from './src/screens/ShowScreen';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = props => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Index'>
              <Stack.Screen name='Index' 
                  component={IndexScreen} 
                  options={{ 
                  title: 'Blogs', 
                  headerRight: () => (
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>
                          <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  )   
              }} />
              <Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' component={ShowScreen} options={{ title: 'Post Details' }} />
              <Stack.Screen name='NewPost' component={CreatePost} options={{ title: 'Create a Post' }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default () => {
    return (
        <Provider>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I got for my question:
**options={({navigation}) => ({
title: 'Blogs',
headerRight: () => (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Provider } from './src/context/BlogContext';
import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen';
import CreatePost from './src/screens/CreatePost';
import ShowScreen from './src/screens/ShowScreen';

import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Index'>
        <Stack.Screen name='Index' 
          component={IndexScreen} 
          options={({navigation}) => ({ 
            title: 'Blogs', 
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost')}>
                <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )   
        })} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' component={ShowScreen} options={{ title: 'Post Details' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='NewPost' component={CreatePost} options={{ title: 'Create a Post' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```